# Cannot read from a closed TextReader me sale este error al tratar de mover un txt a una carpeta

Tags: c#

esto un ejemplo, como ven paso un txt por el StreamReader si este da un error durante el case muevo trato de mover el archivo a otra carpeta difirente de cuanto se lee correctamente pero me da un erro de Cannot read from a closed TextReader. Si me puede ayudar por favor?

```
         foreach (string item in archivos) 
        {
            string archivo = item;

    StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(archivo);

                    string line = "";
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        line = sw.ReadLine();


                        if (line != null)
                        {
                            string lineas = line;



                            Regex r = new Regex("^<([A-Z_]+)\\s*,?(.*)>$");
                            if (!r.IsMatch(line))
                                continue;

                            MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(line);

                             [0].Groups[1].Value.Split(',');
                            string comando = mc[0].Groups[1].Value;
                            string[] parametros = mc[0].Groups[2].Value.Split(',');
                            //string[] parametros = r.Matches(line)[0].Groups[1].Value.Split(',');
  switch (comando)
        case "CERRAR_CF":
                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (oImpFiscal == null)
                                            oImpFiscal = new ImpresoraFiscal(comboBoxComPort.Text, (EpsonFPHostControlX.TxBaudRate)((MyComboBoxItem)comboBoxComSpeed.SelectedItem).Value, htConfig);
                                        string extension = "";
                                        switch (parametros[0])
                                        {
                                            case "0":
                                                extension = "0";
                                                break;
                                            case "1":
                                                extension = "1";
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        extension = extension.PadLeft(3, '0'); // bits 3, 4, 5
                                        extension = extension.PadLeft(16, '0');
                                        extension = Convert.ToUInt16(extension, 2).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');

                                        oImpFiscal.Cerrar("1006", extension, new string[] {
                                            parametros[1].Trim(), //Numero linea de reemplazo #1
                                            parametros[2], //Descripcion de reemplazo 1
                                            parametros[3].Trim(), //Numero linea de reemplazo 2
                                            parametros[4], //Descripcion de reemplazo 2
                                            parametros[5].Trim(), //numero linea de reemplazo 3
                                            parametros[6], //Descripcion de reemplazo 3
                                        });
                                    }

                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        oLog.WriteLog(ex.Message);

                                            File.Move(archivo, RutaError);
                                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                        if (oImpFiscal == null)
                                            oImpFiscal = new ImpresoraFiscal(comboBoxComPort.Text, (EpsonFPHostControlX.TxBaudRate)((MyComboBoxItem)comboBoxComSpeed.SelectedItem).Value, htConfig);
                                        oImpFiscal.CancelarDocumento();




                                        };
                                    break;
                          }
                sw.close();

                 }catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    oLog.WriteLog(ex.Message);
                        //File.Move(archivo, RutaError);
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                }
```

Comment: csharp/C# @Trauma

Comment: trate de darle un poco de identacion al codigo, pero si puedes editalo y subelos de forma que sea entendible

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a iterar las lineas de un archivo recomendaria utilices

```
string lines = File.ReadAllLines(archivo);

foreach(string line in lines)
{
  //resto codigo
}
```

Esto hara mas simple la iteracion de cada linea